# Identifying DJIA data using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm fairly new to coding and am trying to write a script that would pull market data at timed intervals while running, then compare the delta between each pull and notify the user of the change - looking for simple shifts, let's say >.1% in any interval.

My initial approach is to run a Beautiful Soup script to obtain posted market data, using either Yahoo Finance or Barron's, as both seem to have the data available in the HTML code:

https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar

http://www.barrons.com/mdc/public/page/9_3000.html?mod=bol_mdc_topnav_9_3000

This is as far as I've gotten and not having much luck, the find function doesn't seem to be returning anything from the site - looking for any nudging that might help me get on the right track with this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from urllib.request import urlopen

import requests


import pandas as pd

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar'

page = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')


soup.find("span")
```

I would expect this to return the first span tag so I could later hone in on the DJIA data: "

```
span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fz(s) Mt(4px) Mb(0px) Fw(b) D(ib)" data-reactid="31">26,430.14</span
```

but the script runs and returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same url the [bottom of your listed urls](http://www.barrons.com/mdc/public/page/9_3000.html?mod=bol_mdc_topnav_9_3000) is using to source the quote

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://quotes.wsj.com/index/DJIA?mod=mdc_uss_dtabnk')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
djia = soup.select_one('#quote_val').text
print(djia)
```

That is clear as source when you inspect the network traffic of the original bottom url you list and then focus on this url

http://www.barrons.com/mdc/public/js/9_3001_Refresh.js?

which has the js for refreshing that value. There you can see the listed source url for quote.

The response which contains:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! I modified slightly as I was getting an error on the use of 'lxml'

r = requests.get('https://quotes.wsj.com/index/DJIA?mod=mdc_uss_dtabnk')
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
djia = soup.find(id='quote_val').get_text()
print(djia)

Comment: Now i need to add a timed repeat and then do the math on the difference, do you think this is a logical function to run?

#import time, threading

#WAIT_SECONDS = 60

#def djiaGet():
#    print(time.ctime())
#    print(djia)
#    threading.Timer(WAIT_SECONDS, djiaGet).start()

#djiaGet()